# How do I set Chrome to open a New Tab Page at startup rather than my last visited page?

Tags: google-chrome

When I open a new page on Google Chrome, it pulls up the last page that I was on when I closed out instead of the new tab page.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

If you go into your settings menu, you can select startup behavior to be either

1. Open the New Tab Page.
2. Continue where I left off.
3. Open a specific set of pages (with a "Select Pages" link to configure those).

In your case, you'll want to select the "Open the New Tab Page" option.

You can get to the settings by clicking on the button generally found to the right of the Address Bar marked by 3 horizontal lines (appearance may vary by version or themes you have applied).

Comment: It's already set to the Open the New Tab Page option, but it still opens to the last page.

Comment: Same here. The settings don't work. This is the most annoying feature I found after updating to version 37.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your version of Chrome and your default search engine. See https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2918032?hl=en